# AWS ALB Create Path-Based Routing - Redirect subdirectory to root

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

I have one application running on AWS, it runs under the application / directory. I want to create a path-based routing on AWS Load Balancers and run it as two applications, but I get a 404 error. How can I do this with AWS Application Load Balancer without doing anything on the backend?

Structure:

1. domain.com/server1 (AWS Load Balancer) ---> TargetGroup1 --- > /
2. domain.com/server2 (AWS Load Balancer) ---> TargetGroup2 --- > /

In short, when I want to access `https://lbaddress/test1` address, I want the software running on my backend (working on `root folder /` ) server to run

Nginx side, i can do as follows.

```
location ^~ /server1 {
      rewrite ^/server1(.*)$ $1 last; 
}
```

[This rule is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lERUk.png), faced 404 code.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: this nginx config works for me, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 8):

AWS ALB does not support path rewriting. When request `domain.name/server1/foo` is forwarded, the target host will see `/server1/foo`, not `/foo`. Since you likely don't have `/server1` configured on your target host, it will return 404.

Comment: I needed exactly this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your ALB Listeners. In the appropriate listener click on "view/edit rules". There you can add your rules. You want to do a path-based routing, so you will add this rule:

```
IF PATH is /server1/* THEN Forward to TG1
IF PATH is /server2/* THEN Forward to TG2
```

`/*` is added so it matches anything in the path start starts with the appropriate server.

Comment: I already tried it, I faced always 404 code. When i try with Nginx as follow. It works.

location ^~ /server1 {
      rewrite ^/server1(.*)$ $1 last; 
}